# How to skip to next iteration if no results are returned in SELECT statement in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a case where I `SELECT` rows from one table and `INSERT` them to another table. However, I get `Error: 1329 SQLSTATE: 02000` if the `SELECT` statement doesn't return any row. Can I do something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP()
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND;
   BEGIN
      ITERATE
   END
   BEGIN 
      DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM table1;
      OPEN cur1; 
      read_loop: LOOP
         FETCH cur1 INTO var1;
         INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT c1 FROM table3)
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cur1;
   END;
```

Is this correct? Thanks.

EDIT:

Based on answers below, what worked for me was:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE done BIT DEFAULT FALSE; 
    DECLARE name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE lat FLOAT;
    DECLARE lon FLOAT;
    DECLARE radius FLOAT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM anchorage_test;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cur1; 
    read_loop: LOOP
       SET done = FALSE;
       FETCH cur1 INTO name, lat, lon, radius;
       IF done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
       END IF;
       INSERT INTO sp_result
       SELECT imo, draught, ST_Distance_Sphere(point(lon, lat),point(longitude,latitude))*0.000539957 AS distance, dt_pos_utc, name FROM historical_temp HAVING distance < radius;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur1;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error indicates that you're trying to `FETCH` another row from the cursor, when no new row can be found. As McNets indicated, you need to exit the loop once you've read all the data from the cursor.

If the problem is actually that there's no data in the `SELECT` from `table3` (which I wouldn't expect to cause an error), you can check to make sure the `SELECT` returns at least one row.

The following adds both checks to your existing code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP()
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
   BEGIN
      ITERATE
   END
   BEGIN 
      DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM table1;
      OPEN cur1; 
      read_loop: LOOP
         SET done = FALSE;
         FETCH cur1 INTO var1;
         IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
         IF EXISTS (SELECT c1 FROM table3) THEN
            INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT c1 FROM table3)
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cur1;
   END;
```

Note: It's possible that the `NOT FOUND` condition could be raised by the `SELECT` from `table3`; we don't want that to kick us out of the loop, so I ensure that `done` is `FALSE` right before we execute the `FETCH`.

Not sure all of the above is necessary - code is untested.

Comment: This code didn't work as it is, but the ideas in this helped me get the right SP. Would you like to update teh answer so I can mark it as right? I will include the code that worked for me based on your answer as an edit.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer with the corrected code; glad I could be of some help!

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use: [LEAVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/leave.html) loop_name

```
IF NOT EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM table3 WHERE <some condition>)
    LEAVE read_loop;
```

Comment: I don't want to exit, I want to skip to next iteration.

Comment: Leave exits the loop, not the procedure

Answer (score 0):

Again, avoid `CURSORs`.

Is the `*` only one column?  If not then the `FETCH` won't work because it expects only one column.

You aren't using `var1`?

```
INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT c1 FROM TABLE3
       WHERE .... -- Maybe var1 comes into play here??
```

Comment: In my final solution, I did away with the SP altogether and went with a CROSS JOIN. SP brought down the execution time to about 55 minutes. CROSS JOIN brought it down to 35 minutes. Thanks for the advice.